# opensource free subversion for personal web site

Tags: svn, hosting, public

I am building my personal web site and would like to upload and share my code with others through this web site. What i am looking for is a free subversion, where i will only have commit access but the rest users will have download access. The site will not describe one specific project, doing something specific but i.e. examples of tutorials i will write, code which i commonly re-use, small indemendent modules which can be reused, etc.
    I looked over web, and found too many free subversion repositories, however, some mention a limit on users, some like 'Google Project Hosting' are like creaing a specific project, etc. Most if not all are propably good for me, but would like to get some proposal/feedback on if someone has already done something similar and what he would propose.

Comment: Offtopic and RTFM-ignorance detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using GitHub at [it supports SVN](https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion) in addition to git.

Comment: When these two say "Free for open source"
Can i limit who will commit/change my code?

Comment: Nobody will be able to `push` changes to your own code with a public account on GitHub...

Comment: thank you.
GitHub is exactly what i was looking for, already started using it

Answer (score 0):

[Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/home) has a free SVN repository (and some paid options)

Comment: GitHub seemed better fit to my needs but Assembla seems quite good as well

Answer (score 0):

Personal website with "examples of tutorials i will write, code which i commonly re-use, small indemendent modules which can be reused" isn't SCM, it's blog or Wiki

Comment: just to answer this and make my answer more clear. I have a blog and wished to have in my articles a link for users to download full source. So yes, you are correct, a blog would be the answer, if i only wished to have some article and some code snippets, but what i wish is to have the complete source/solution accessible for my readers.

Comment: @Alexandros - add upload area to blog and store zips